# Inserting Image to Email using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments

I have the following snippet of VBA code ran in Excel which sends emails to our customers. I'm trying to insert a picture into the body of the email. The below code works fine when sending to my internal Outlook email, but does not work when sending to my personal Gmail account, meaning that the image does not show. Maybe because the LetterHead filepath is within our network? Help would be much appreciated!

```vb
Dim MItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim LetterHead As String
LetterHead = "file path to .png file located in company network drive"

For x = 1 To xlList.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    PolNum = xlList.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 7).Value
    PolSubj = Subj & PolNum
    
    With MItem
        .To = EmailAddr
        .Subject = PolSubj
        .HTMLBody = "<center><img src=" & Chr(34) & LetterHead & Chr(34) & "></center>" & StrBody & .HTMLBody
        .Send
    End With
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603108/8422953

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe because the LetterHead filepath is within our network?

Yes, you are on the right avenue. You need to upload the image to any web server to make it available for others. Be aware, email client application may block internet images automatically.

If you need to make sure the image is displayed to a user you need to attach the image to the mail item (see [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add)) and then set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` MAPI property (the DASL name is "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F") using [PropertyAccessor.SetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor.setproperty) and refer to the attached file using the `src` attribute that matches the value of `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property value set on the attachment object. For example:

```
attachment = MailItem.Attachments.Add("c:\temp\MyPicture.jpg")
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "YourPictureId")
MailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>This is an embedded image <img src=""cid:YourPictureId""></body></html>"
```

The `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property corresponds to the `Content-ID` MIME header when the message is sent.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer has a local file path, so if I get this to work, I won't need to host the image on a web server..?

Comment: Yes, correctly. You may attach the file to the email (embedded image) and then refer to it in the email body.

Comment: Linking to a publicly hosted file would require the least amount of code changes on my end.. I'm gonna talk with my IT department to find a place to host my image. Or maybe just use an image already on our website.

Comment: Attaching a file to the email doesn't require it to be hosted on any web server.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertImageInEmailBody()

    Dim ImageFilePath As String, xMailBody As String
    
    ' Set the image file path
    ImageFilePath = "C:\path\to\file\picture.png"
    
    xMailBody = "<BODY>Hi,<br> <br>This is the pic<br><br>" & _
        "<img src='" & ImageFilePath & "'><br><br>" & _
        "Thank you.</BODY>"
    
With CreateObject("outlook.application").CreateItem(0)
        .To = "someone@somewhere.com"
        .Subject = "Here it is"
        .HTMLBody = xMailBody & .HTMLBody
        '.Attachments.Add
        .Display
        '.send
End With
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The path is valid only for the local machine (sender). The recipient may use a different machine.